# Advice on my graphing project

Tags: c++, math, scripting, lua, graphing

I'm working on a program that will update a list of objects every (.1) seconds. After the program finishes updating the list, the program will be aware if any object is within a certain distance of any other object. Every object has an X,Y position on a graph. Every object has a value known as 'Range'. Every tick (.1s) the program will use the distance formula to calculate if any other objects are less than or equal to the range of the object being processed.

For instance, if point A has a range of 4 and is at (1,1) and point B is at (1,2), the distance formula will return ~1, meaning point B is within range of point A. The calculation will look similar to this:

```
objects = { A = {X = 1,Y = 1,Range = 4}, B = {X = 1,Y = 2,Range = 3}, C = {X = 4,Y = 7,Range = 9} }

while(true) do
 for i,v in pairs(objects) do
   v:CheckDistance()
 end
wait()
end

-- Point:CheckDistance() calculates the distance of all other points from Point "self".
-- Returns true if a point is within range of the Point "self", otherwise false.
--
```

**The Problem**:
 The graph may contain over 200 points, each point would have math applied to it for every other point that exists. This will occur for every point every .1s. I imagine this may slow down or create lag in the 3D environment I am using.

**Question**: 
 Does this sound like the optimal way to do this?
 What are your ideas on how this should be done more efficiently/quickly?

Comment: It sounds like you're rolling your own collision detector. Many 3D environments will do this for you. Also--as this is a well-studied problem, there are many optimizations that can be performed (for example, storing the points in an octree so you can ignore most of them and reduce N) so you probably want to do a bit of research before reinventing the wheel.

Answer (score 3):

As [Alex Feinamn](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12787532/advice-on-my-graphing-project#comment17288000_12787532) said: it seems you are making your own collision detector, albeit a primitive one.

I'm not sure if you have points on a 2D or 3D plane, however. You say every object "has an X,Y position on a graph" and further on talk about "lag in the 3D environment I am using."

Well, both 2D and 3D physics – as well as Lua – are well developed fields, so there are no shortage of optimisations.

## Spatial Trees

A [quadtree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadtree) (or [octree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Octree) for 3D) is a data structure that represents your entire 2 world as a square divided into four squares, which are each divided into four squares, and so on.
[image: An example of a quadtree]

You can experiment with an interactive example yourself at [this handy site](http://www.cs.utah.edu/%7Ecroberts/courses/cs7962/project/).

Spatial trees in general provide very fast access for localised points.
[image: An example of searching in a quadtree]

The circles represent the interaction radius of a particular particle. As you can see, it is easy to find exactly which branches need to be traversed.

When dealing with point clouds, you need to ensure two points do not share the same location, or that there is a maximum division depth to your tree; otherwise, it will attempt to infintely divide branches.

I don't know of any octree implementations in Lua, but it would be pretty easy to make one. If you need examples, look for a Python or C implementation; do **not** look for one in C++, unless you can handle the template-madness.
Alternatively, you can use a C or C++ implementation via Lua API bindings or a FFI library (recommended, see binding section).

## LuaJIT

[LuaJIT](http://luajit.org/luajit.html) is a custom Lua 5.1 interpreter and just-in-time compiler that provides significant speed and storage optimisations as well as an FFI library that allows for easy and efficient use of C functions and types, such as integers.

Using C types to represent your points and spatial tree will significant improve performance.

```lua
local ffi = require"ffi"
ffi.cdef[[
    // gp = graphing project
    struct gp_point_s {
        double x, y;
        double range;
    };
    
    struct gp_quadtree_root_s {
        // This would be extensive
    };
    struct gp_quadtree_node_s {
        // 
    };
]]

gp_point_mt = {
    __add = function(a, b)
        return gp_point(a.x+b.x, a.y+b.y)
    end,
    __tostring = function(self)
        return self.x..", "..self.y
    end
    __index = {
        -- I couldn't think of anything you might need here!
        something = function(self) return self.range^27 end,
    },
}
gp_point = ffi.metatype("struct gp_point_s", gp_point_mt)

-- Now use gp_point at will

local p = gp_point(22.5, 5.4, 6)
print(p)
print(p+gp_point(1, 1, 0))
print(p:something())
```

LuaJIT will compile any runtime usage of gp_point to native assembly, meaning C-like speeds in some cases.

## Lua API vs FFI

This is a tricky one...

Calls via the Lua API cannot be properly optimised, as they are in authority over the Lua state.
Whereas raw calls to C functions via LuaJIT's FFI can be fully optiised.

It's up to you to decide how your code should interoperate:

- Directly within the scripts (**Lua**, limiting factor: dynamic languages can only be optimised to a certain extent)
- Scripts -> Application bindings (**Lua** -> **C/C++**, limiting factor: Lua API)
- Scripts -> External libraries (**Lua** -> **C**, limiting factor: none, FFI calls are JIT compiled)

## Delta time

Not really optimisation, but it's important.

If you're making an application designed for user interaction, then you should not [fix your time step](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/1589/fixed-time-step-vs-variable-time-step); that is, you cannot assume that every iteration takes exactly 0.1 seconds. Instead, you must multiply all time dependant operations by time.

```lua
pos = pos+vel*delta
vel = vel+accel*delta
accel = accel+jerk*delta
-- and so on!
```

However, this is a physics simulation; there are distinct issues with both fixed and variable time steps for physics, as discussed by Glenn Fiedler:

> #### Fix your timestep or explode
>
> ...  If you have a series of really stiff spring constraints for shock absorbers in a car simulation then tiny changes in dt can actually make the simulation explode. ...

If you use a fixed time step, then the simulation should theoretically run identically every time. If you use variable time step, it will be very smooth but unpredictable. I'd suggest asking your professor. (This is a university project, right?)

Comment: Yes this is a college project, i've been researching octrees and spacial mapping. At this moment, i'm thinking of using region specific point movement listeners. One point can have a high enough value to be within range of points way out of its own region. I'm thinking of ways I can keep track of every point and the points within range of each n point.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know whether it's possible within your given circumstances, but I'd definitely use events rather than looping. That means track when a point changes it's position and react to it. This is much more efficient as it needs less processing and refreshes the positions faster than every 1 second. You should probably put in some function-call-per-time cap if your points float around because then these events would be called **very** often.

Comment: As a minimum optimization I'd start by using native C++ functions and operate on arrays of objects instead of on individual ones. Lua is a stack based language so Lua function calls can be expensive